# How to get Bigcommerce Developer certification

Tags: certificate, bigcommerce

I have work experience in Bigcommerce, am interested to get Bigcommerce developer certificate for that i have searched in google,but i did not get single line information about Bigcommerce Cerrtificate, can any one please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't currently an open certification process for BigCommerce, but there is one available to be certified as a partner of BigCommerce with expertise in Stencil.

For information on applying to the tech app partner program: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/#apply-to-the-technology-partner-program

To apply as a design solution partner: https://www.bigcommerce.com/partners/design-solution/

Tech app partner typically denotes folks that are making api integrations as apps to sell to BigCommerce store users. Design Solution partners means people that are making more specific changes to storefronts or work in/around the frontend.